# How to reshape WDI data

Tags: r, reshape

I need to reshape some data I downloaded from the worldbank database. However I have some difficulties with it.

The goal is that it looks like this:

```
year CH DE US
1980 17383.38 11746.40 12179.56
1981 15833.74 9879.46 13526.19
1982 16133.97 9593.66 13932.68
1983 16007.82 9545.86 15000.09
1984 15229.82 9012.48 16539.38
```

I use the following code to download data. WDI and RJSONO packages are required.

```
wdi <-  WDI(country = c("CH","DE","US"), indicator = "NY.GDP.PCAP.CD" ,start = 1980, end = 2010, extra = F)
```

then I reshaped the following way:

```
wdi2 <- reshape(wdi, direction = "wide", timevar="year", v.names="NY.GDP.PCAP.CD", idvar="country", drop="iso2c")
```

The output does not match my expectations of how it should look:

```
> wdi2
             country NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2010 NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2009 NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2008
    1    Switzerland            70572.66            65790.07            68555.37
    32       Germany            40163.82            40275.25            44132.04
    63 United States            46615.51            45305.05            46759.56 ...
```

This one is a bit better but still not what I want:

```
> t(wdi2) 
                    1             32          63             
country             "Switzerland" "Germany"   "United States"
NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2010 "70572.66"    "40163.82"  "46615.51"     
NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2009 "65790.07"    "40275.25"  "45305.05"     
NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2008 "68555.37"    "44132.04"  "46759.56"     
NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.2007 "59663.77"    "40402.99"  "46349.12"
```

The wdi object looks like this:

```
> wdi
   iso2c       country NY.GDP.PCAP.CD year
1     CH   Switzerland      70572.657 2010
2     CH   Switzerland      65790.067 2009
3     CH   Switzerland      68555.372 2008
4     CH   Switzerland      59663.770 2007
...
30    CH   Switzerland      16219.906 1981
31    CH   Switzerland      17807.340 1980
32    DE       Germany      40163.817 2010
33    DE       Germany      40275.251 2009
34    DE       Germany      44132.042 2008
...
62    DE       Germany      11746.404 1980
63    US United States      46615.511 2010
64    US United States      45305.052 2009
```

Comment: On my phone, but it seems like you might just be looking for `t(wdi2[-1])` after which you can add back in the column names and clean up the row names.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thx. However isn't their a smarter way that puts the data directly to the right format by using only the reshape function?

Comment: As I said, on my phone :) Please post a few lines of your wdi object and I'll see what comes to mind.

Comment: For starters, it's not clear why you would use `direction = "wide"` when it seems like you want a long output form.

Comment: Added selected lines from the wdi object. From my perspective I have to go from long to wide, don't I? Because my goal is to use country codes as column headers.

Comment: This looks like a job for `dcast` from the "reshape2" package, now that you've shared a data sample. Maybe `dcast(wdi, year ~ country, value.var = "NY.GDP.PCAP.CD")`

Comment: `xtabs` in base R might be worth checking out too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In front of a computer again... so here's an update.

As mentioned in my comments, `dcast` from "reshape2" is quite convenient for this. You can get similar functionality from `xtabs` in base R if you're just doing the reshaping step.

```
x <- xtabs(NY.GDP.PCAP.CD ~ year + iso2c, wdi)
head(x)
#       iso2c
# year         CH        DE       US
#   1980 17807.34 11746.404 12179.56
#   1981 16219.91  9879.457 13526.19
#   1982 16527.46  9593.657 13932.68
#   1983 16398.24  9545.859 15000.09
#   1984 15601.26  9012.479 16539.38
#   1985 15748.95  9125.121 17588.81
```

`xtabs` creates a `matrix` of `class` "xtabs", so to get a `data.frame`, wrap the output in `as.data.frame.matrix`.

```
head(as.data.frame.matrix(x))
#            CH        DE       US
# 1980 17807.34 11746.404 12179.56
# 1981 16219.91  9879.457 13526.19
# 1982 16527.46  9593.657 13932.68
# 1983 16398.24  9545.859 15000.09
# 1984 15601.26  9012.479 16539.38
# 1985 15748.95  9125.121 17588.81
```

---

To answer your other question you had asked in your comment: *However isn't their a smarter way that puts the data directly to the right format by using only the reshape function?*. The answer is "Yes. Just swap what you were using for the "idvar" and "timevar" in your original `reshape` attempt."

```
y <- reshape(wdi[-2], direction = "wide", idvar="year", timevar="iso2c")
## Optional step to clean up the resulting names
names(y) <- gsub("NY.GDP.PCAP.CD.", "", names(y))
head(y)
#   year       CH       DE       US
# 1 2010 70572.66 40163.82 46615.51
# 2 2009 65790.07 40275.25 45305.05
# 3 2008 68555.37 44132.04 46759.56
# 4 2007 59663.77 40402.99 46349.12
# 5 2006 54140.50 35237.60 44622.64
# 6 2005 51734.30 33542.78 42516.39
```

When using the `reshape` function, sometimes it helps to ignore the "id" and "time" parts of the argument names and think instead about where they are to go. ID variables usually make up a column, and time variables usually spread out wide, one column for each time. So, even though we might think of "country" as the actual ID variable, for the data format that you want, it is more of a time variable.

Hopefully this helps, even though you've already accepted an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

It is really easy to achieve using `reshape2`.

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(wdi[,-2], year ~ iso2c, value.var = 'NY.GDP.PCAP.CD')
```

EDIT. Oops, I did not see the comment posted by Ananda Mahto with the same solution. Anand, if you post your comment as an answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: No problem. Not in a position to verify, so I didn't want to post anything. Is it necessary to drop unwanted columns before casting?

Comment: Actually, no. But, I wanted to make it clear that you will be dropping a column effectively.

Comment: Added an answer with two base R solutions to complement this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```
# renames the NY.GDP column and drops all but two columns
trans_one <- function(dat) {
    newcol <- dat[1, "iso2c"]
    idx <- which(colnames(dat)=="NY.GDP.PCAP.CD")
    colnames(dat)[[idx]] <- newcol
    dat <- dat[,c(newcol, "year")]
    dat
}

# split by country
sp <- split(wdi, wdi$iso2c)

# merge 
fun <- function(x,y) {
    merge(x, trans_one(y), by="year", all=TRUE)
}   
Reduce(fun, x=tail(sp, -1), init=trans_one(sp[[1]]))
```

However, the `reshape2` looks more straightforward to me now.

Comment: That seems to be a very painful base R approach. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19211791/1270695) for `xtabs` and `reshape` solutions, both part of base R.